# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I deployed my application on Tomcat Web Application Manager, AWS EC2. When I use Postman to test POST method, I got this error.

```
<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title>
    <style type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
    <p><b>Message</b> &#47;mobile-app-ws&#47;users</p>
    <p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
        willing to disclose that one exists.</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.51</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

1. I am sure tomcat8 and MySQL are running.

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-187 ~]$ sudo service tomcat8 status
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-187 ~]$ ..                           [  OK  ]
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-187 ~]$ sudo service mysqld status
    mysqld (pid  3852) is running...
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-187 ~]$
```

2. My instance on EC2 is running well.

```
--    Instance State      Status Checks
--    running.            2/2 checks passed
```

3. Java version of My application and on EC2 are both 1.8.

```
--[ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-187 ~]$ java -version
--openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
--OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
--OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
--[ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-187 ~]$
```

4. My application extends SpringBootServletInitializer, and override its `SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)`
5. Application name on Tomcat Web Application Manager is `/mobile-app-ws`.
6. Public DNS for my instance is `ec2-54-215-197-6.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
7. URL for POST, `http://ec2-54-215-197-6.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/mobile-app-ws/users`
8. context path for my application, `server.servlet.context-path=/mobile-app-ws`

--Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, my application is working well on my Mac.

Comment: What are the security groups on the instance?

Comment: Can you check port 80 is open for incoming requests?

Comment: Security Group ID is  sg-0e69ef87179cfb0f7.

Comment: Security Group name is launch-wizard-1.

Comment: I have checked that my security group, my http port range is 8080.

Comment: Did you check your application logs?